# When predicting a binary outcome with strictly binary predictors, does logistic regression yield the same results as OLS?

Tags: regression, logistic, linear

I was recently presented with the prompt, essentially, to make the case for why logistic regression is the better choice (over OLS) when predicting a binary outcome with a set of binary predictors.

In the case of continuous predictors, this would be a relatively straightforward answer. But after running some simulations for myself, I realized that I was getting the same coefficients (after transformation back to probability from log odds in the logistic case) between both models.

I cannot convince myself that there is actually a pragmatic difference between the two models, but I am sure there must be - particularly since a binary outcome would violate the assumption of normality of OLS.

If there is a more in-depth explanation of why this might be the case, I would love to learn a bit more.

Comment: For estimating parameters, OLS does *not* assume Normality.  Moreover, if you are focused on the parameter estimates only, then distributional assumptions are irrelevant.  In your simulations have you included at least two explanatory variables? Have you included an interaction term or not?  With an interaction the predictions will be identical, but otherwise they likely will differ a little, and therein may lie the basis for an interesting response to the prompt.

Comment: When you do simulations, what happens to the variability of coefficient estimates when you use either method?